# How to copy and paste lines in Nano on OSX

Tags: command-line

I would like to copy and paste multiple lines in the command line text editor nano on OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.5

Alt-6 and Ctrl-U do not work as on other platforms.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that in Mac Terminal, the `alt` key doesn't work unless you change the Terminal Preferences to enable `Use Option as Meta key`. Then `alt+6` will work properly to `copy`.

Another choice is to use the `ESC` key instead of `alt`. So do `ESC+6`.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to cut multiple lines into a buffer using Ctrl-K, and paste them back in using Ctrl-U.

Note that this does not copy the text onto your OS X clipboard, but uses a buffer inside of `nano` (or the shell?) to perform the actions.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to paste text from clipboard just use 
Cmd + V - works well

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! That works for current versions of macOS, would it work for OS X Lion as requested by the OP?

Comment: My macOS version is Catalina

Answer (score 0):

In my case my clipboard was getting bracketed.

Typing `reset` in the terminal window (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) fixed my issue and allowed me to paste in nano with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> as usual.