# Copy and Paste Lines in Nano on MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line, keybindings

I am on ARM-based MacOS Sonoma 14.

For some reason, I have no luck with the 'copy' step from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/281582/502004) to the same question on OS X. I have tried both with and without the 'use Option as Meta key' button, i.e, `Esc+6` / `Esc+Shift+6` & `Option+6` / `Option+Shift+6`. I needed to use `Ctrl+Shift+6` to set/unset mark. Has `nano`'s behavior changed, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: For me too it doesn't work

Comment: ESC-6 works for me on Sonoma, without "Option as Meta" set. Is it only "Copy" which doesn't work for you, or do "Undo" and "Set Mark" not work either?

Comment: @nohillside i can (un)set marks, but ESC-U (undo) and ESC-6 (copy) don't work. interestingly, i tested in a Linux VM on the same machine, and all of these work just fine, using ESC as Meta key.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I installed `nano` via Homebrew ages ago, totally forgot about that. macOS doesn't even include `nano` any longer, `/usr/bin/nano` is just a symlink to `pico`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `nano` is [(now)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367003/502004) symlinked to `pico` v5.09, it seems 'Undo' and 'Copy' are still [disabled by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41657607/22673230).

Use `brew install nano` (followed by [`hash -r`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211501/502004)) to install the latest version of `nano`, along with enabling these features.